# low-pass filter and the sharp cut-off filter

Tags: lowpass-filter

are the low-pass filter and the sharp cut-off filter the same thing??

Here there is the definition of sharp cut-off filter https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_(large_eddy_simulation) .

I tried to obtain with matlab the Fourier transform of the low-pass filter, but I noticed that I don't reach the low pass filter. What am I doing wrong?

```
x=-100:0.1:100
delta=5
G=sin(pi*(x+eps)/delta)./(pi*(x+eps))
H= abs(fft(G))
Tinc=0.01
Fs=1/Tinc;

freq =transpose( -Fs/2:Fs/length(G):Fs/2-(Fs/length(G)));
figure()
plot(x,G)
figure()
plot(freq,H)
```

Comment: From your link "The LES filter operation is low-pass, meaning it filters out the scales associated with high frequencies". BTW, the sharp cut-off filter is not in the link but a sharp spectral filter is which is a type of LES filter and therefore a LPF.

Comment: So is the sharp cut-off filter a type of low-pass filter? is the box filter an other kind of box filter?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by a sharp cut-off filter. A google search did not yield any results on the matter, Can you support the definition of such a name with either a book or a paper? Do you mean something else maybe?

Comment: the two terms mean different specifications of a filter.  *"low-pass"* is a **type** of filter as are "*band-pass*" and *band-reject* (sometimes called *"notch"* filters) and *"high-pass"*.  the *"sharpness"* of the cutoff is a quantitative specification of the degree of discrimination the filter performs between frequencies that are passed and frequencies that are rejected.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson so is the Sharp spectral filter a kind of LPF?

Comment: @Arkadiuszduka as we tried to explain you, that's not possible to say. "Sharp" specifies the steepness of the edges, whereas "low pass" specifies the position of the pass band. What you're asking is "is 'red car' a kind of 'fast car'?", and that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Following the OP’s wikipedia link, the “physical space” and “spectral space” are the Fourier conjugate domains. Then the so-called “box filter” is an ideal low pass filter in the “physical space” and the so-called “sharp spectral filter” is an ideal low pass filter in the “spectral space”. Not a very clear wikipedia article, frankly, and the terminology is unorthodox, especially “sharp spectral filter”. Hope this helps a bit!